# When to add calculated custom columns to a query - right away or by using a join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to add two columns to the query below:

- 1st column would be the % of free space = `freespace/capacity`
- 2nd column would be the amount of used space = `capacity-freespace`

This is my query

```
SELECT     SystemName, Caption, Label, Capacity, FreeSpace
FROM         CCS_Win32_Volume
ORDER BY SystemName, Caption

USE [CentralConfigurationStore]
GO
```

Would adding it to the query or doing it after and joining the two tables be the better approach?

If anyone could help me out with this it would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculated fields will not add much overhead when you add them right into the query, since the data you're calculating on has already been read from disk.

```
SELECT SystemName, Caption, Label, Capacity, FreeSpace,
       100*freespace/capacity [% of free space],
       capacity-freespace [used space]
FROM CCS_Win32_Volume
ORDER BY SystemName, Caption
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8cdfb/4).

Answer (score 1):

I think the question was the approach, not the actual T-SQL...

Unless your query is used elsewhere and changing it might break something, then I would update your existing query. 
If it is used elsewhere and it's going to be a lot of work to update all the related processes/queries then I would create a separate query with the complete results. There seems little point in creating a query with just the calculated values in because, as you stated, you'll then have to join it back to your original query, which just seems like more work for nothing.

Anyway, that's just my personal opinion.

Regards,

Al.

Comment: I was asking about both the logic behind it and T-SQL, I appreciate your explanation :) 1up!

Answer (score -1):

Just alias the computer values. Also, you should put the USE command first:

```
USE [CentralConfigurationStore]
SELECT     SystemName, Caption, Label, Capacity 
   , FreeSpace, freespace/capacity AS FreeSpacePercent
   , capacity-freespace AS UsedSpace
FROM         CCS_Win32_Volume
ORDER BY SystemName, Caption
```